# Is it right that you can have function vectorspaces were all vectors are functions , but functions are also lineare maps between vectorspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I came to the conclusion that functions obbey the axioms of a vectorspace thus there exist a function vectorspace were all vectors are functions. But functions can also be a lineaire map between vectorspaces right? (1,first question)
(second question 2) thus there exist lineaire maps between function of vectorspaces right?
I would like all your tips on how you guys think of this , and make it intuitive and maybe even visualize

Comment: Yes, given two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over a field $F$, the set of linear maps $V\to W$ form a vector space over $F$ with the operations of addition and composition of maps. This vector space is denoted $\mathcal L(V,W)$ or $\operatorname{Hom}_F(V,W)$, the vector space of homomorphisms $V\to W$. You can read more in the wiki [Linear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Vector_space_of_linear_maps).

Comment: If $V$ is a vector space, and $X$ is a set, then $V^X = \{\textrm{functions } X \to V\}$ is also a vector space with the pointwise operations (meaning, if $\lambda$ is a scalar and $f,f_1,f_2$ are in $V^X$, then $f_1+f_2 \in V^X$ sends every $x \in X$ to $(f_1+f_2)(x) := f_1(x)+f_2(x)$ and $\lambda f \in V^X$ sends every $x \in X$ to $(\lambda f)(x) := \lambda f(x)$). If $U$ is another vector space (over the same field) then $\operatorname{Hom}(U,V) = \{\textrm{linear maps } U \to V\}$ is a subspace of $V^U$, as you can check.

Comment: Yes, you can have a vector space where the vectors are linear maps between vector spaces.  You can have a vector space of colors or dog's names or candybars as well so long as you appropriately define the vectorspace operations and scalar field correctly too... It doesn't really matter what sort of objects they are in the vector space and their relation to other mathematical objects or contexts which they are used in.  Of course, certain vector spaces are *more interesting* and *more useful* than others in certain contexts, but don't let that be the only thing you focus on.

Comment: @jMoravitz Good tip I will try to keep my idea of a vectorspace very broad